# Can Coupon and Payment panes be on the same page?

Tags: 7, commerce

I have a checkout process where the payment pane and coupon are on the same page. The issue is when the coupon gives 100% discount, I would like to change the available payment method to a free order that does not require a credit card. But what the coupon is applied with ajax, the cart gets updated, but the payment methods do not.

The only idea I've had is to listen to the `.ajaxComplete()` event, and when the price is 0, refresh the page. Obviously, I would like to have something smoother that works with ajax.